# How to create a river using NEST client for ElasticSearch

Tags: rest, nest

I'm beginning to work with Elastic Search on our MVC5 project.

We have continuous integration build in place, and would like to configure Elastic Search via NEST just like Entity Framework Code-First.

I'm struggling to find how I can invoke this request through NEST.

```
PUT _river/mytype/_meta

{
    "type":"jdbc",
    "jdbc": {
        "driver":"com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver", 
        "url" : "jdbc:sqlserver://127.0.0.1:1433;databaseName=MyDatabase;",
        "user" : "user",
        "password" : "password123",
        "sql":"select * from RiverView",
        "poll":"30s",
        "index":"myindex",
        "type": "mytype",
        "strategy": "simple"    
    }
}
```

Does anyone have any idea how to do this?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to make this work with using ElasticClient.Raw

```
        var client = CreateClient();

        var river = new
        {
            type = "jdbc",
            jdbc = new
            {
                driver = "com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver",
                url = String.Format("jdbc:sqlserver://{0}:1433;databaseName={1};", "127.0.0.1", "myDatabase"),
                user = "user",
                password = "password",
                sql = "select * from mySqlView",
                poll = "30s",
                index = "index",
                type = "type",
                strategy = "simple"
            }
        };

        string body = client.Serializer.Serialize(river, Formatting.Indented);

        //HACK: Second parameter is a hack, appended _meta to type because NEST doesn't implement MetaPut()
        var response = client.Raw.IndexPut("_river", "mytype/_meta", body);
```

Might not be the most elegant but worked for my requirement.